# Spring security authentication simple login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the following configured in my app-config.xml:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" />
    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"

                users-by-username-query="
                  select login, password 
                  from accounts where login=? and password=?" 

                authorities-by-username-query="
                  select a.login, ar.authority from accounts a, account_roles ar 
                  where a.account_id = ar.account_id and a.login =?  " 

            />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

However When I start my application, and it displays the login for I get the following error message:

> Reason: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select login, > password from accounts where login=? and
>   password=?]; SQL state [90012]; error code [90012]; Parameter "#2" is
>   not set; SQL statement: select login, password from accounts where
>   login=? and password=? [90012-170]; nested exception is
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Parameter "#2" is not set; SQL
>   statement: select login, password from accounts where login=? and
>   password=? [90012-170]

Any ideas whats wrong?

I am not totally sure how the security:jdbc-user-service works? How does it fill in the = in my select query?

My database is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
  account_id VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  login VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (account_id)
);
CREATE TABLE account_roles (
  account_id VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  authority VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (account_id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_account_roles FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES accounts (account_id)
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name of parameter `users-by-username-query` means that query will do search by username only, so I suggest to modify your SQL query to something like this:

```
users-by-username-query="select login, password, 'true' as enabled from accounts where login=? limit 1"
```

Comment: I have tried that as well and get this message:
Reason: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select login, password from accounts where login=? limit 1]; SQL state [90008]; error code [90008]; Invalid value "3" for parameter "columnIndex" [90008-170]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Invalid value "3" for parameter "columnIndex" [90008-170]

P.S. I updated the original post with my DB schema.

Comment: @john-sam I've updated my answer. Query must return 3 values: `login`, `password` and `enabled` property. Because your scheme lacks `enabled` property I modified SQL query to always returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

As Slava pointed out you need an indication if the user is enabled or not. Here is a reference to the documentation of Spring Security 3.2.6.RELEASE: [UserDetailsService](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#userdetailsservice-implementations). Here is what it says:

> The returned UserDetails is an interface that provides getters that guarantee non-null provision of authentication information such as the username, password, granted authorities and whether **the user account is enabled or disabled**.

It's a bit misleading if you only read the docs for [DaoAuthenticationProvider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#core-services-dao-provider), which states:

> It leverages a UserDetailsService (as a DAO) in order to lookup the username, password and GrantedAuthority s. It authenticates the user simply by comparing the password submitted in a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken against the one loaded by the UserDetailsService.